# Solving Problems of the Type $\log(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$

Tags: logarithms

I have recently been struggling to solve the following advanced mathematics problem which is presented as $|0.1 x^2 + 2 x + 3| = \log(x)$. I know that before solving the problem, it must be taken into account that the initial equation must have both positive and negative aspects on the left side since there exists a modulus, therefore:

$$\begin{align}
0.1 x^2 + 2 x + 3 = \log(x)\\
-0.1 x^2 - 2 x - 3 = \log(x)
\end{align}$$

But from then on I do not have any idea as to how to solve such problems which are of the form $\log (x) = a x^2 + b x + c$. I think that it has something to do with getting rid of the log, but I do not know how to do it cleanly. If I take everything to the exponential of 10, I would have $x$ by itself but then I would have the problem $10^{-0.1 x^2 + 2 x + 3} = x$ and I am stumped by that as well. I would be much obliged if anyone could provide advice as to how such a problem could be solved.

Comment: First of all I guess this has nothing to do with the [Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). It would be more likely that the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) will appear somewhere since it is defined as the inverse function of $f(x)=xe^x$ for the purpose to solve similiar equations like yours. But I am not sure if there is a closed-form solution for general $a,b,c$. In your case the solutions are given by $x=-1.19812\mp 1.31258i...$ for the first equation and $x=0.0454515...$ for the second one according to  WolframAlpha.

Comment: I doubt there is any closed-form solution to this type of equation. I am not sure that even the Lambert W would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$0.1x^2+x+3=0.1(x+5)^2+0.5>0$$
we have that
$$|0.1x^2+2x+3|\ge 0.1x^2+2x+3>x>\log x$$
The equation has no real solution.